# NSArrayURL , userDefault filePath and URL

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, nsurl, userdefaults

I have one pdf source code and I want to add the Url in Array and use UserDefault

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

struct Constants {

    static let myKeyURL = "myKeyUrl"

}
```

I download the Pdf Like This

```
let documentsPath =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

let fileName = urlString as NSString;
let filePath="\(documentsPath)/\(fileName.lastPathComponent)";
```

After I save the Path like This

```
var arrayUrl = [String]()
arrayUrl.append(filePath)
self.defaults.set(arrayUrl, forKey: Constants.myKeyURL)
```

Now I want to Read

```
var arrayUrl = [String]()
defaults.stringArray(forKey: Constants.myKeyURL)
arrayUrl = defaults.stringArray(forKey: Constants.myKeyURL)!
```

I need to Read in This Model

```
documents = arrayUrl.flatMap { PDFDocument(url: $0 ) }
```

But I received 
**Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL'**
I need this URL (**arrayUrl**) File in this format **file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/----/Documents/Sample.pdf**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear:

`PDFDocument(url:` expects `URL`, you pass `String` which is a classic type mismatch.

You have to create URL instances from the strings

```
documents = arrayUrl.flatMap { PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: $0) ) }
```

However you are discouraged from saving the full path because the path to the Documents folder changes. Save only the file name or relative path and get the actual path to the Documents folder on each application launch.

Comment: You should mention that OP should only save the file name and which directory it is located. The actual file path might change